# How to access the fields of this struct in Golang

Tags: go, struct

I'm new to Golang and I need to know how to access the value from a struct of the format:

```
type CurrentSkuList struct {
    SubscriptionNumber   string `json:"subscriptionNumber`
    Quantity             int    `json:"quantity"`
    SubscriptionProducts []struct {
        ID              int    `json:"id"`
        ActiveStartDate int    `json:"activeStartDate"`
        ActiveEndDate   int    `json:"activeEndDate"`
        Status          string `json:"status"`
        Sku             string `json:"sku"`
        ChildIDs        []int  `json:"childrenIds"`
    } `json:"subscriptionProducts"`
}
```

For example, if I have a variable `currentSkus` of type `CurrentSkuList` and I need to access only `Sku` and `Status` values, is there a way to do something like:

`currentSkus.SubscriptionProducts.Sku`?

EDIT! When I try to access `currentSkus.Quantity` I get a compiler error `undefined (type []util.CurrentSkuList has no field or method Quantity)`.

Comment: `currentSkus.SubscriptionProducts[<index within bounds of slice>].Sku`. E.g. if your slice has exactly one element then you can do `...[0].Sku`. Alternatively you can loop over the slice with `for`.

Comment: so when I try to to something like you said, I get a compiler error `undefined (type []util.CurrentSkuList has no field or method SubscriptionProducts)`

Comment: That means that the variable you have is also a slice and its elements also need to be accessed through an index. i.e. your statement *"I have a variable `currentSkus` of type `CurrentSkuList`"* is false.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah, there is a way. You can access by the `.` syntax you proposed. In this case, CurrentSkuList is returning an slice of SubscriptionProduct, you know that because of the `[] struct` part. Then you would have to access to the data this way:

```
currentSkus.SubscriptionProducts[index].Sku
```

Comment: so when I try to to something like you said, I get a compiler error `undefined (type []util.CurrentSkuList has no field or method SubscriptionProducts)`

Comment: You could show a little bit of the initialization of the object. If you are receiving that error is because the atribute was not defined there.

Comment: at the comments of the question, someone already helped me!